# Magento - Error creating Partial Payment using Paypal Express

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, paypal

I'm trying to create a module for allowing Partial Payment during checkout process.

Let's take a cart with 2 products, first item = 1000€ and second item = 500€.

User has to pay 1500€ but I'm allowing to split the payments in two steps, first user will pay 1000€ and later he'll has to pay 500€.

When trying to use Paypal Express payment for this, I'm always getting this error:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. 
Item total is invalid (#10426: Invalid Data). 
The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts 
(#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. 
See additional error messages for details).
```

Basically, what I'm doing is modifying `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express` overwriting the value of `Amount`:

```
$transaction_amount = $this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
if ($this->_quote->getPartialpayment_price() > 0) {
    $transaction_amount = $this->_quote->getPartialpayment_price();
}

$this->_api->setAmount($transaction_amount)
        ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
        ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
        ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
        ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
        ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
        ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

Is it somehow possible to avoid what Paypal is internally checking, to compare the final amount with the cart item amounts?

Answer (score 0):

In order to not send the individual items to Paypal API Request, there's an option in the backend named `Transfer Cart Line Items`. If it's set to NO we won't add each cart item into that request.

[image: Paypal Request]